# Update Table From Select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using ms-sql server. I have `table` which I want to `update` from `select statement`. For example the table which I want to update is `Table_A` with `2 rows` in it. The update statement from which I want to update Table_A return `10 rows`. So I want to `update Table_A 10 times`. The problem is that Table_A is `updated 2 times`(`the count of rows in Table_A`).

**Example:**

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    AccountID INT,
    Inflow DECIMAL(10,2)
)


DECLARE @n INT = 0
WHILE (@n <10 )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT 2, 10
    SET @n += 1
END

UPDATE  dbo.Table_A
SET     Balance += sss.Inflow
FROM    ( SELECT    t.AccountID ,
                    t.Inflow
          FROM      #tmp AS t
        ) AS sss
WHERE   dbo.tAccount.AccountID = sss.AccountID;

-- Updates only 2 times
-- What I expected here is Table_A to be updated as many times as the count of the select statement which is 10, based on the insert before.
```

Comment: First, I am guessing that you are using SQL Server, based on syntax.  Second, your expectation is wrong.  A row only gets updated once.

Comment: Yes it updates only once. My expectation was to be updated 10 times based on the count of the select statement with syntax like this.

Comment: You can only update what is in Table A.  If it only has 2 records then only those 2 can be updated.  You would need to insert the other 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expectation is wrong.  Admittedly, the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) buries this idea:

> The example runs without error, but each `SalesYTD` value is updated
>   with only one sale, regardless of how many sales actually occurred on
>   that day. **This is because a single `UPDATE` statement never updates the
>   same row two times.**

The documentation continues with the solution:

> In the situation in which more than one sale for a specified
>   salesperson can occur on the same day, all the sales for each sales
>   person must be aggregated together within the `UPDATE` statement, as
>   shown in the following example:

So, simply aggregate before doing the `join`:

```
UPDATE  dbo.Table_A
SET Balance += sss.Inflow
FROM (SELECT t.AccountID, SUM(t.Inflow) as Inflow
      FROM #tmp t
      GROUP BY t.AccountId
     ) sss
WHERE dbo.tAccount.AccountID = sss.AccountID;
```

Note you can also write this as:

```
UPDATE a
SET Balance += sss.Inflow
FROM dbo.Table_A a JOIN
     (SELECT t.AccountID, SUM(t.Inflow) as Inflow
      FROM #tmp t
      GROUP BY t.AccountId
     ) sss
     ON a.AccountID = sss.AccountID;
```

This makes the `JOIN` more explicit.